# Get Random File Order in Dos FOR Command

Tags: for-loop, dos

Here is DOS

`FOR /R folder %%f in (*.filetype) DO something`

I like to achieve, when each time run this, random file order will be feed to `something` from FOR loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to record the file names prefixed by a random numeric key in a temporary file, sort the lines by their random keys and then extract the file names in their new order. This can be accomplished with the DOS commands `type` and `sort` like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set tempfile=_%RANDOM%_%RANDOM%_%RANDOM%_.tmp
type nul >%tempfile%
for /R folder %%i in (*.filetype) do set key=!RANDOM!!RANDOM!!RANDOM!000000000000& echo !key:~0,15!%%i>> %tempfile%
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type %tempfile% ^| sort') do set line=%%i&set file=!line:~15!&something
del %tempfile%
```

Notice that the tokens `folder` and `filetype` in your example are on the first for-line (where the writing to the temporary file is done), while `something` is on the next line.
instead of `something`, you could write here for example `echo !file!` to print the file names to the console.